# Get index from several columns in listView

Tags: c#

below I have some code to get the index from the selected row in a listView. But this only works if the user clicks on the first column. But if I have four columns, how would I do to let the user click anywhere on a row of the listView?

```
private void lvRegAnimals_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = lvRegAnimals.FocusedItem.Index;
    // Code here to pass the index to method....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [`ListView.FullRowSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect.aspx) to true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ListView.SelectedItems` property to do the work here,
Something like this

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged_UsingItems(
        object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection breakfast = 
            this.ListView1.SelectedItems;

        double price = 0.0;
        foreach ( ListViewItem item in breakfast )
        {
            price += Double.Parse(item.SubItems[1].Text);
        }

        // Output the price to TextBox1.
        TextBox1.Text = price.ToString();
    }
```

For more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: Hmmm, looks a bit complicated compare to the other answer, but thanks anyway!